# How I could embed my recent Instagram posts in html without using a third party widget?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, embed, instagram-api

**I'm trying to embed my recent Instagram posts on a website.**
I'd used instafeed.js, but it's not working anymore due to the change that instagram made to their API.
How I could embed the posts in my html without using a third party widget?
and if there isn't a solution other than using third party are there any free widgets to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think the policy changed and you need an api key now. Check [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) for more info. If you have a key you could make calls to the api to get posts and embed them on your website. No need for a third party widget.